# maintain previous div height after ajax call

Tags: javascript, css, ajax

I am dealing with the following issue.
I have a script that is calling ajax in which the response contains cart string (html code) with items of my cart.
Withtin the responsehandler I have another script that is setting each of the divs of the ajax response cart string to a certain height.

Now I am willing to maintain the div height that was set to the previous cart string, but the problem is the entire cart string is received over again after every ajax call.

In addition I have another cart (mobile only) which shows up in a bootstrap modal. Somehow this function for setting the height is not working on unless you open it and run the function again. Does this have something to do with the modal display:none? The function is looping through all div with same class name and sets the height according to its child data.

Comment: Can you share your code snippet

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the div's height by using css.

```
div.cart-height{
  height: 400px !important;
}
```

or after ajax call, resize the div's height.

```
$('.cart-height').css('height','400px');
```

In mobile you can adjust content:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .cart-height {
    height: 200px;
  }
}
```